# How to add inline form to Inline form in django admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

how do i make 2 nesting levels with default django admin methods  (i want include C fields to form)

## models.py example

```
Example:
class A(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   block_a=models.OneToOneField(A,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="block_b")

class C(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    block_b=models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="block_c")
```

## page example

how i can create django admin model with inline form in inline form
form example:

```
    title(class A)
    other_fields
    
    B:
        title(class B)
        other_fields
    
        C:
            title(class C)
            other_fields
        C:
            title(class C)
            other_fields
        C:
            title(class C)
            other_fields
```

## admin.py

#its work

```
class AInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = A
    form = AForm

class B(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = B
    form = BForm
```

but how do i make 2 nesting levels with default django admin methods  (i want include C fields to form)